# How to only display 5 most recent records in database - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

so what I am trying to do is display the 5 most recent records stored in the database to appear on the "Create" View. The table is stored in "_Recent" which is a partial view of the table. the table appears in the "Create" View but how can I make it that only the 5 most recent records display instead of all the contents.

**_Recent (Partial View)**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="table-title">
    <table class="table-fill">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DisplayName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaxBonus)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

</div>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td clas="text-left">

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayName)
            </td>
            <td class="text-left">

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td class="text-left">

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td class="text-left">

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaxBonus)
            </td>
            <td class="text-left">

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>

        </tr>


    </tbody>

}

</table>
```

**Create View**

```
<div class="table-title">
   @Html.Partial("_Recent", Model);

</div>
```

**Create Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(db.Donations.ToList());
    }
```

**Charity Class**

```
    public class Charity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Double Amount { get; set; }
    public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}

public class CharityDBContext : DbContext //controls information in database 
{
    public DbSet<Charity> Donations { get; set; } //creates a donation database
    public Charity Highest { set; get; }
    public CharityDBContext()
    {
        this.Highest = new Charity();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(db.Donations.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(5).ToList());
}
```

you can also use `OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)`. Good practice is to have dates (columns and properties) when the record was **created** and when it was **updated**, so you can sort by those fields.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do is:

1. Order the records by the needed fields (OrderByDescending)
2. Limit the result to the records needed (Take)
3. And last, materialize your result from database (ToList).

`return View(db.Donations.OrderByDescending(d => d.ID).Take(5).ToList());`

This makes the query to execute in the underlaying database engine and only get the exact number of records from the database table.

Answer (score -2):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(db.Donations.OrderByDescending(o => o.ObjectID).Take(5).ToList());
}
```

Please check capital letters, I'm not in visual studio now.

**UPDATED**

Comment: This will take first 5 and then reverse them, without guarantee they will be reversed by Id.

Comment: Sorry, i make a mistake, the .OrderByDescending() go before .Take(5)

Comment: There is no `OrderByDescending` overload that takes no arguments. You always have to provide a Func or lambda.